# How to get Id of a element using class name?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, javascript, aura, html

I have an anchor tag with the class name "Active". How do I get the Id of the tag with the class name "Active"? Or how can i change the class="active" to class=" "?

```
 <a aura:id="Home" href="{!v.status}" id ="dashboard" class="active" alternativeText="DASHBOARD" title="DASHBOARD"> 
</a>
```

Please help me with this?

I have tried getting using `document.getElementsByClassName("active")`. But the length of the array is being displayed as 0.

Comment: where are you using `document.getElementsByClassName("active")`? Is it in `init` handler?

Comment: No, It is not in Init handler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use binding:

Define an attribute called `dashboardLinkClass`

```
<aura:attribute name="dashboardLinkClass" type="String" default="active"/>
```

reference that in your link:

```
<a aura:id="Home" href="{!v.status}" 
   class="{!v.dashboardLinkClass}" 
   alternativeText="DASHBOARD" title="DASHBOARD"> 
</a>
```

And set/unset it as you like in the controller or helper:

```
component.set("v.dashboardLinkClass","");
```

This way you don't need to worry if the markup has finished rendering or not - the attribute will always be there.